# Laravel Guest User with additional login

Tags: laravel, authentication

I would like to build a possibility to add register the guest user afterwards...

So the use case is like that> 
The User gets a GuestAccount imediately when he opens the pages and is already logged in. Afterwads he gets a result that is linked to this Account
Then he decides to register and open up the page in another device where he needs a login inorder to get the same result from the original GuestAccount.

in StartController

```
        if(!Auth::check()){
            $user = User::create([
                'name' => 'guest', 
                'email' => 'guest@guest.com'
            ]);
            Auth::login($user, true);
        }
        return view('guest');
```

Afterwads the Auth::user() should be able to login one more time to his "real" account - if he has one.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Auth::logout() to log him out. But I think the correct method would be to log him in with a unique email and not guest@gmail.com - something like 
tempemail124121@gmail.com

and then after registration, you simply update the user in that session with the correct email.

Comment: but how to get the link the result to the new one?